# Taking value in the Maskformater

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield, maskformatter

I have wrote a program for taking IP address`(Ex. 172.16.10.0)`. I am using Maskformatter but dont how take the value from the Maskformatter.

```
try {
    MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter(mask);
    JFormattedTextField txtIP = new JFormattedTextField(mf);
    panIP.add(txtIP);
    txtIP.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
    txtIP.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 150, 24 )); 
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I pass the value`(Ex.172.16.10.0)` that is taking in the textfield to another string variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the value by simply calling

`txtIP.getText()`;

as if it was normal TextField.